# Freeing memory with Pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c++

C++ newb here. I'm trying to write my own implementation of an array using only pointers, and I've hit a wall I don't know how to get over.

My constructor throws this error

```
array.cpp:40:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
```

When my array initializes I want it to free up all the spaces in the array for ints.

```
Array::Array(int theSize){
size = theSize;
int *arrayPointer = new int; 
int index = 0;
while(theSize > index){
  *(arrayPointer + index) = new int; //This is the trouble line.
  ++index;
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong stackoverflow?

Comment: Well, for starters you're attempting to allocate each element individually, when there's a built-in `new int[size]` syntax for array allocation ;-)

Comment: Using `new int[size]` is just as bad (possibly worse). For a container, you normally want to use `buffer = operator new(size);` to allocate raw storage, followed by placement new to create objects in that space: `new(buffer+pos) int(value);` This matters little with `int`, but much more with other types.

Comment: Since this comes up so often, and nearly always produces a slew answers I think are mostly wrong, I wrote up a [blog post](http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html) about what I consider a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayPointer` points to a single `int`, it does not point to an array of `int*`, which this line would require:

```
*(arrayPointer + index) = new int;
```

but the type of `*(arrayPointer + index)` is an `int`, hence the compiler error.

To allocate an array of `int`:

```
int* arrayPointer = new int[size];
```

If this is intended to initialise a member variable then:

```
arrayPointer = new int[size];
```

otherwise `arrayPointer` would be local to the constructor. As the class now has a dynamically allocated member you need to either implement both copy constructor and assignment operator or prevent copying (see [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)). Remember to `delete[] arrayPointer` in the destructor.

---

Just mentioning `std::vector<int>`, even though this is a learning exercise.

Comment: I tried new int[size] and the program hurled. Is there an include I need to use?

Comment: Did you redeclare `arrayPointer` in the constructor (see updated answer)?

Comment: Still hurling, forgot to post the error.

`array.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to operator new[] (unsigned int)'`


Thanks for the link, I'll read more into it.

Comment: @Breedly, what are compiler are using? GNU? If so, use `g++` and not `gcc`.

Comment: Hah, problem solved, only to add more problems out of the scope of this question! Thanks so much, you were a huge help. Feel good about yourself for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
class Array
{

public:

    T* const arrayPointer; // arrayPointer can't be reallocated
    const size_t size; // size can't change

    Array(const int theSize) : arrayPointer(new T[theSize]),
                               size(theSize) {}

    ~Array() {
        delete[] arrayPointer;
    }

private:

    Array(const Array& other) {} // forbid copy

    Array& operator= (const Array& other) {} // forbid assignment

} ;
```

- Why to use `template <typename T>`? So you can have an array of any type.
- Why to use `new T[ theSize ]` ? So you can allocate `theSize` elements at the same time.
- Why to use `: arrayPointer( new T[ theSize ])` ? So in case allocation fails (due to big theSize) the object fails without initialization. It is callled RAII.
- Why to use `delete [] arrayPointer` ? Because you used `new[]` and you have to deallocate the whole array.
- Why those `const`'s? To avoid anyone changing the size of the array and making the fields inconsistent.
- What are these private methods? They are forbiding copies, so no one can make `array1 = array2; delete array2;`, what would deallocate the arrayPointer of array1.

Usage (it will allocate array of 10 int:)

```
Array< int > arr( 10 ) ;
```

Access:

```
arr.arrayPointer[ 0 ] = 5 ;
```

Note - you can access `arrayPointer` at the cells of range 0..9. You can add `operator[]` to your class in order to avoid using `arrayPointer` and to use `arr[ 0 ]`.

Comment: This is also a great answer, but it goes a little out of scope. You should feel good about yourself too for the next couple of days!

Comment: @Breedly: I have just started feeling good about myself ;) Seriously, since you are a newbee to C++ then why not start the right way? And since you want to implement your ownr array, I think it is the best and safest way too. Have fun with C++.

Comment: @Grzegorz Nice things to teach, but maybe too early. Now that you have shown that he needs a Destructor, you probably need to talk about the Rule of Three, otherwise it will not be "the best and safest way".

Comment: @AlexOliveira: There is never end to how much one can learn ;) Yes, there is so much into it... pure C++ is really cool.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Agree! I tried to edit you code to make it adhere to the Rule of Three without complicating it too much.

Comment: @AlexOliveira: Thanks for the effort. Approved.

Answer (score 0):

The line you mentioned is trying to set a int* into a int var => Dereferencing a int* provide a int :

```
*(arrayPointer + index) // is a int
```

Anyway you are moving in memory (and dereferencing memory) you haven't reserved. So you can access a protected memory zone by doing this instruction.

Replace all your constructor with:

```
Array::Array(int theSize)
{
    size = theSize;
    arrayPointer = new int[theSize]; // Replace your local var with a member one. Else you will lose your array ;)
}
```